# How to get D-U-N-S number for building ios apps?

Tags: registration, ios-app-group

We,want to build and develop IOS apps for my corporate office which was located in India But to build IOS apps for enterprise we need to have DUNS number. Can any one help me

1.How to get DUNS number for my corporate office in India ?

2.What is the requirement for my corporate office to get DUNS number ?

3.What are the charges are to get DUNS number ?

Comment: I am not sure but CA may help you.

Comment: Whats ment by CA.?

Comment: Chartered Accountant

Comment: Oh thanks for your suggestion Mr.Kamal

Answer (score 0):

There is a DUNS lookup page on enrol page.

https://developer.apple.com/enroll/duns-lookup/

Fill your company details and DUNS number will be emailed to you within 5 minutes.